# How to Do EC Compression on a Public Key in Python?

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am trying to find the Python-equivalent of running `openssl ec -pubin -in example.pem -inform PEM -outform DER conv_form compressed`

**Example using the following public key:**

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk
6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ1snzreGB+pyoiUUkz2/H60XWmQsgC7zZ60TBT0rVimtg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and running the following command gives the following output:

```
echo '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk\r\n6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ1snzreGB+pyoiUUkz2/H60XWmQsgC7zZ60TBT0rVimtg==\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n' | openssl ec -pubin -inform PEM -outform DER -conv_form compressed | base64

read EC key
writing EC key
MDkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDIgAC4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ0=
```

now providing a bit more verbosity with the same command plus the -text flag and minus the base64 encoding:

```
echo '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk\r\n6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ1snzreGB+pyoiUUkz2/H60XWmQsgC7zZ60TBT0rVimtg==\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n' | openssl ec -pubin -inform PEM -outform DER -conv_form compressed -text

read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
pub:
    02:e2:af:a8:b7:ba:37:3e:e2:6a:b0:1a:27:66:78:
    b6:b2:95:4f:be:a2:e4:e8:50:a2:10:5f:46:5f:34:
    f2:61:9d
ASN1 OID: prime256v1
NIST CURVE: P-256
writing EC key
090*�H�*�H�="⯨��7>�j�'fx���O����P�_F_4�a�%
```

**So far I am able to do something like:**

```
import base64
import cryptography
csr_crypto = cryptography.x509.load_pem_x509_csr(csr_encoded) # csr_encoded being the CSR in PEM format that the public key is derived from
pub_key = csr_crypto.public_key()
compressed_bytes = pub_key.public_bytes(cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.Encoding.X962, cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.PublicFormat.CompressedPoint).hex()
```

this leads to `compressed_bytes` being equal to

`02e2afa8b7ba373ee26ab01a276678b6b2954fbea2e4e850a2105f465f34f2619d`

which if you look closely is equal to what is in the `pub` above.

How are these hex bytes ultimately converted to the string `MDkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDIgAC4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ0=` that openssl outputs as a compressed public key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first key posted is a public key in X.509/SPKI format (PEM encoded), which contains the actual key in *uncompressed* format `0x04 + <x> + <y>`.
The key derived from this using the OpenSSL statement is also a public key in X.509/SPKI format, but contains the actual key in *compressed* format `0x02 + <x>` or `0x03 + <x>` for even or odd `y`, respectively. This format also contains the complete information, since for a given curve an uncompressed key can be derived from a compressed key.
X.509/SPKI keys can be parsed with an ASN.1 parser (in addition to OpenSSL), e.g. online: https://lapo.it/asn1js.

---

In Python, an X.509/SPKI key with uncompressed key can be converted to an X.509/SPKI key with compressed key using the *PyCryptodome* library, see [`export_key()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/ecc.html#Crypto.PublicKey.ECC.EccKey.export_key):

```py
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto.PublicKey import ECC

x509PemWithUncompressed = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk
6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ1snzreGB+pyoiUUkz2/H60XWmQsgC7zZ60TBT0rVimtg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''

publicKey = ECC.import_key(x509PemWithUncompressed);
x509withCompressed = publicKey.export_key(format='DER', compress=True)
print(b64encode(x509withCompressed).decode('utf-8')) # MDkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDIgAC4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ0=
```

---

The *Cryptography* library on the other hand only allows the export of an X.509/SPKI key with uncompressed key. For this, the format has to be specified with [`SubjectPublicKeyInfo`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo). An export as X.509/SPKI key with compressed key is not possible. The options [`UncompressedPoint`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.PublicFormat.UncompressedPoint) and [`CompressedPoint`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.PublicFormat.CompressedPoint) only allow export in the format `0x04 + x + y` or `0x02/0x03 + x`, but not in the X.509/SPKI format.

But there is a workaround for the desired conversion. In the X.509/SPKI format, the actual key (compressed or uncompressed) is located at the end. The preceding part contains information about the curve, data lengths, etc. In the case of an X.509/SPKI key with *compressed* key and curve P-256, the preceding part is: `0x3039301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107032200` (note that the prefix for an X.509 /SPKI key with *uncompressed* key differs because of the different data lengths) and can be used as a prefix for converting a compressed key in `0x02/0x03 + x` format to X.509/SPKI format:

```py
from base64 import b64encode
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

x509PemWithUncompressed = b'''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk
6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ1snzreGB+pyoiUUkz2/H60XWmQsgC7zZ60TBT0rVimtg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''

publicKey = serialization.load_pem_public_key(x509PemWithUncompressed) 
compressedKey = publicKey.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.X962, serialization.PublicFormat.CompressedPoint)
x509withCompressed = bytes.fromhex('3039301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107032200') + compressedKey 
print(b64encode(x509withCompressed).decode('utf-8')) # MDkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDIgAC4q+ot7o3PuJqsBonZni2spVPvqLk6FCiEF9GXzTyYZ0=
```

Comment: You are amazing!!